# Jmeter Script to upload all files in a folder?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test an API using Jmeter.

http://localhost:8080/fileupload

This API take a single file as as a parameter and uploads it to my App

[image]

Now I have a folder which contains 1000's of such files.

How do I write a script in Jmeter that picks up 1 file from the folder and then sends a request (i.e. 1 request for each file) and this continues for all the files in the folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) and [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) combination like:

1. Add Beanshell Sampler to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   File folder = new File("c:\\somefolder");

   File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
       public boolean accept(File file) {
           return file.isFile();
       }
   });

   for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
       vars.put("file_" + i, files[i].getAbsolutePath());
   }
   ```

   The above code will generate JMeter Variables like:

   ```
   file_1=C:\somefolder\somefile.txt
   file_2=C:\somefolder\someotherfile.jpg
   ```
3. Add ForEach Controller **after** the Beanshell Sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Input variable prefix: `file`
   - Output variable name: anything meaningful, i.e. `currentFile`
   - Check `Add "_" before number

   [image: Foreach controller]
4. Put the HTTP Request sampler which performs file upload under the ForEach Controller
5. Put `${currentFile}` to "File Path" input

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on enhancing your JMeter tests with Beanshell

Comment: This is exactly what is wanted! Ill try this and let you know :-)

Comment: Is it possible if JMeter can automatically pick the files from the source folder and store it to the destination folder ??

Answer (score 1):

To make JMeter upload all files:

First create a CSV file that contains the file names

Then use a [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with 2 columns:
- 1 that will contain the path to files, let's say you name it pathToFile 
- 1 that will contain the mime type of the file, let's say you name it mimeType

[image]

Then in your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) , select "Files Upload" Tab and use the variables:

Note you must change:

- paramName in the table to match what you have in your form.
- path to match your URL suffix
- host
- port if different from 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS

[image]

Comment: This method definitely works. But is longer than @Dmitri T answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's longer, what I am sure of is that it is standard, maintainable and performs much better than Beanshell sampler. Read JMeter best practices: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223 .

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by using the solution  provided here :

http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/fileUploadInJMeter.html

and keeping the file name like:

abc-${counter}.png

where the `counter` is a counter variable which increments with each request.
Also, files in the folders too are like  abc-1.png abc-2.png etc.